# Biztalk. Compare given xml and message

Tags: xml, xslt, mapping, compare, biztalk

Boss told me to compare received message in xml format with xml given file that contains information about DB. I need to do it in Biztalk using xslt mapping. I can do declarative part of this task. I've even found [xslt that compare 2 xml files.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546190/compare-two-xml-files-with-xslt)  But I dont know how to do it in biztalk.

What I need is a Biztalk-compatible xslt that just takes the input message and takes the given xml file that is situated in solution box and compare it either using the method above or  the one you think is more suitable for my situation. Please show places to insert filenames or messagenames in needed format

The file contains only this kind of information

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<DocumentElement>
  <Columns>
    <OWNER>APEX_030200</OWNER>
    <TABLE_NAME>APEX_APPLICATION_ALL_AUTH</TABLE_NAME>
    <COLUMN_NAME>WORKSPACE</COLUMN_NAME>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <DATATYPE>VARCHAR2</DATATYPE>
    <LENGTH>255</LENGTH>
    <NULLABLE>Y</NULLABLE>
    <CHAR_USED>B</CHAR_USED>
    <LENGTHINCHARS>255</LENGTHINCHARS>
  </Columns>
  <Columns>
    <OWNER>APEX_030200</OWNER>
    <TABLE_NAME>APEX_APPLICATION_ALL_AUTH</TABLE_NAME>
    <COLUMN_NAME>APPLICATION_ID</COLUMN_NAME>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <DATATYPE>NUMBER</DATATYPE>
    <LENGTH>22</LENGTH>
    <NULLABLE>Y</NULLABLE>
    <LENGTHINCHARS>0</LENGTHINCHARS>
  </Columns>
</DocumentElement>
```

Comment: I understand that you need to compare the input xml to some other xml. But what output do you want? What should that look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the values that you are checking against are not changing, this could easily be done on a BizTalk map.
You just use the functoid "Logical equal" and then enter the value you are checking against. From this you get a Boolean that together with a “value mapping” functoid can be used to create an output message.
Of cause you can also use the “logical AND” functoid to add several value checks.

If you need to check against an existing file, I can see two possible ways:

1. Create a validation function in a referenced class, and call this
   function from a BizTalk map (functoid “Scripting”).
2. Create a custom pipeline that does the valuation.